# Bound mismatch for java Collections sorting

Tags: java, collections, comparator

Hi need Help regarding java collection sorting. It gives me this error:

```
Bound mismatch: The generic method sort(List<T>) of type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (List<WifiSSID>). 
The inferred type WifiSSID is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Comparable<? super T>>
```

My code looks like:

```
public class WifiSSID {

    public String SSIS;
    public double id;
}


 public class ScanFilterWifiList {

    public ScanFilterWifiList(List<WifiSSID> wifiList) {
        Collections.sort(wifiList);
           //Collections.sort(wifiList, new SortSSIDByid()); tried this also.
    }
}
interface Comparator<WifiSSID>
{
    int compare(WifiSSID obj1, WifiSSID obj2);
}

class SortSSIDByid implements Comparator<WifiSSID>
{
    @Override
    public int compare(WifiSSID ssid1, WifiSSID ssid2) 
    {
        int value = 0; 
        if (ssid1.id > ssid2.id) 
            value = 1; 
        else if (ssid1.id < ssid2.id) 
            value = -1; 
        else if (ssid1.id == ssid2.id) 
            value = 0; 
        return value; 
     }
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't sort a List of objects that don't implement the `Comparable` interface. Or rather, you can, but you have to provide a `Comparator` to the `Collections.sort()` method.

Think about it: how would `Collections.sort()` sort your list without knowing when a WifiSSID is smaller or bigger than another one?

You want to use `Collections.sort(wifiList, new SortSSIDByid());`

EDIT:

You defined your own proprietary `Comparator` interface, and implement this proprietary Comparator interface in `SortSSIDByid`. `Collections.sort()` wants an intance of `java.util.Comparator`. Not an instance of your proprietary Comparator interface, that it doesn't know.

Comment: Thank you for help. I update my question. I provide comparator to collection.sort(); But still not working. And what you suggesting my WifiSSID mush implement comparable class ?

Comment: No, I'm suggesting to pass a comparator to Collections.sort() . Define "not working" if you want more help.

Comment: So what to do and How to do this ?

Comment: Delete the Comparator.java source file. And fix the compilation error you'll get in SortSSIDByid by adding `import java.util.Comparator;`.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this import `import java.util.Comparator;`

and remove this interface

```
interface Comparator<WifiSSID>
{
    int compare(WifiSSID obj1, WifiSSID obj2);
}
```

Your `SortSSIDByid` comparator class will now implement `java.util.Comparator` and that is what is required by the `Collections.sort()` method.